# how to check an dispatch_async block has finished running

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

So basically I need to be able to run a segue after a block has finished running. I have a block which does some JSON stuff and I need to know when that has finished running.

I have a queue which I have called json_queue.

```
jsonQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.jaboston.jsonQueue", NULL);
```

I then have a dispatch_async block with this syntax:

```
  dispatch_async(jsonQueue, ^{
  [self doSomeJSON];
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltomenu" sender:self];
  });
```

It wont let me perform the line: "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltomenu" sender:self];"

Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Where can I check to find out when the thread has done its dirty work so i can call the segue?

Thankyou lovely people.

PS: beer and ups and teddy bears and flowers to whoever can help <3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should call UI methods on main thread only. Try to dispatch performSegueWithIdentifier: on main queue:

```
dispatch_async(jsonQueue, ^{
    [self doSomeJSON];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltomenu" sender:self];
    });
});
```

Comment: you sir has upvote and beer. (that is the answer I was looking for!). I totally forgot you could jump back to the mainqueue at any point. brilliant.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff. Why is this better than using performSelectorOnMainThread inside the block?

Comment: @jimbob I should've mention, that using `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async` in third line would be better in this case (I've edited that). This pattern is recommended in WWDC2010 Session 206 video. @ranReloaded Using another block is more convenient because you don't need to create whole new method for such simple task, and what's great, you can access every variable within scope of block definintion.

Comment: you should NEVER dispatch_sync on main queue, always dispatch_async. You may run the risk of temporarily freezing your UI

Answer (score 7):

```
    dispatch_async(jsonQueue, ^{
        [self doSomeJSON];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltomenu" sender:self];
           //Finished with async block

        });
    });
```

Comment: i voted it up because it is also the correct answer but unfortunately the guy above answered with a little extra info. But thankyou so much!