# IOS NSURLConnection and NSthread

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

Im am new to IOS Im building a http request with a response from the server when the request is complete. I have however created a new object to handle the request ...

As far as i can see the request is handled Asyncronusly which makes sure my app does not hang when the request is being processed

Keep in mind I run this request in a new object

```
-(void)signup
{

NSLog(@"Signeduop");
//placing all the form fields in an array
NSArray *fieldsArray;
NSArray *keysArryay;
keysArryay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"e_mail"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MobileNo"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DeviceType"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AppleKey"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FamilyKey"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ServiceCompany"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First_Name"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last_Name"],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID"],
              nil];

fieldsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_email.text],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_telNo.text],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"APPLE"],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PlaceheldforKey"],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_familyKey.text],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_serviceKey.text],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_firstname.text],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_lastname.text],
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_id.text]
               ,nil];



NSDictionary *ValKeyDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:fieldsArray      forKeys:keysArryay];
NSError *error1 = [NSError alloc];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:ValKeyDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error1];
NSString *jstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@" ===== %@", jstring);



HttpClass * hy = [HttpClass alloc];

NSInteger varx = 45;

[hy setMode:(int *)55];
//[hy AppWayRegistration:(NSInteger *)varx : jstring] ;

dispatch_queue_t Queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.plump___________", 0);
//dispatch_queue_t high =     dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0);
//dispatch_set_target_queue(Queue);
dispatch_sync(Queue, ^{ [hy AppWayRegistration:(NSInteger *)varx : jstring]; });
//dispatch_d  Queue);

    int d =hy.RegistrationSucceededMethod;
    NSLog(@"%d joooono",d);

[hy RegistrationSucceededMethod];
//NSLog(@"J -- %d",[hy RegistrationSucceededMethod]);



}
```

After the code has run it is supposed to set a bool Value the sub class [hy RegistrationSucceededMethod];

that bool is set when the NSURLConnections deligate has run in my other class

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection
{
 //do something with the data
    NSLog(@"Suckceeded! recieved %d bytes of data",[recieveData length]);

    RegistrationSucceeded = TRUE ;
    //[self RegistrationSucceededMethod];

}
```

My question is how do I wait for a thread to finish a network operation before calling the object(i.e thread is finished)

My second question is is the thread aware of the connectionDidFinishLoading as its a deligate method in the object and does it run on that thread

My third question is what is the Normal way of dealing with http Request responses where your ios app is waiting for that response to perform the next task

Many thanks to one that solves this one!!

Comment: I think this answers your 3. question: When you download asynchronously you usually do not need a thread. That's what `NSURLConnection` does for you. You put things you want to do when all data has been loaded in `NSURLConnection`s [`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009947-CH1-BAJHIAJA)

Answer (score 0):

1. like a completion block, but via dispatch.
   [how to check an dispatch_async block has finished running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550962/how-to-check-an-dispatch-async-block-has-finished-running)
2. not sure
3. depends.  One option is an activity wheel view with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out 
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler]

It executes the completion block when it finishes the request. Inside of the completion handler, you can then access the data that was downloaded and then perform other operations.

I advise using blocks as much as you can because they can make your life so much easier once you gain better control of them. They help avoid making wrapper classes to contain delegate callback methods and I think also just contribute to code readability because you are basically saying

```
[obj doThisFunction:^{
    andThenThisWhenYouFinish;
}];
```

[Apple docs on blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

I like blocks a lot, but I think they would help you deal with your http responses.

Comment: Ill definitely try this as-well I didn't use blocks before as i didn't fully understand them and the wrapper class is unfortunately necessary as there will be many http posts and responses from the server Not the same info but many of them so I wrap them in a reusable class for organisation sake ... as far as I know blocks data is static and wont take global vars into consideration... Thanks for the imput

Comment: Yeah, blocks are best when you are just trying to download a file or something but aren't great if you want to handle all of the request delegate methods. One thing that I have done in the past is actually create a handler class that I initialize with properties that are blocks which handle all of the various delegate callbacks. That way I can just set up the class with all the callbacks and not worry about handling callbacks later.

Comment: Well that's pretty much what I have been trying to do here... So the wrapper works great the only thing is how to determining when the wrapper has finished its Job hence the  dispatch_sync so once complete I can grab the data ... Or were you referring to a Block Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer...I abandoned Dispatch_async and Used NSthread ...It helped me here and a quote from apples dev docs

*The simple way to initialize an NSThread object in OS X v10.5 and later is to use the initWithTarget:selector:object: method. This method takes the exact same information as the detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject: method and uses it to initialize a new NSThread instance. It does not start the thread, however. To start the thread, you call the thread object’s start method explicitly, as shown in the following example:*

```
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                    selector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod:)
                                    object:nil];
[myThread start];  // Actually create the thread
```

By using the thread methods of -isFinished -isExecuting I'm able to see when to call my bool method, if the method is still executing I simply run a timmer on a new thread to  check in 5 seconds

For anyone that gets stuck with threading

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html